# Is there any way to extend chrome's __commandLineAPI

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, google-chrome-devtools

Google Chrome devtools comes with an extended API provided by so called Command Line Api. API reference can be found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api). Access to the API is implemented by wrapping console input with `with` statement like this:

```
with (__commandLineAPI || { __proto__: null }) {
    //blah-blah-blah your code goes here
}
```

Suppose I want to add my own methods to `__commandLineAPI` object. For example `debugAll` function that takes any object and invoke `debug` for all function properties. Is there any way to extend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can modify the __commandLineAPI directly, but a chrome extension could provide extra global functions which you can use.

There's not a lot of info, but see [here on the chrome site](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#additional-apis) where they say:

> Chrome extensions can inject additional helper methods into the commandline API. For example, the Debug Utils extension (github) offers hooks for breaking on property access, event firings, and method calls.

Also, there's an example they provide [on github](https://github.com/amasad/debug_utils)

That example uses `devtools_page` key in manifest.json to specify an HTML page to load for each instance of DevTools open and the [chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow) to provide functions globally